Question regarding the Generalized Mean Value Theorem
Suppose we are given functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)\ge 0, g(x)\ge 0$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$ and $f,g$ are differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose $f'(x)=u(x)v(x)$ and $g'(x)=u(x)w(x)$ such that $u(x)\ge 0$, $v(x)\ge 0$ while $w(x)> 0$ (i.e only $w$ is strictly greater than zero). The generalized mean value theorem states that there exists a point $c$ such that $(f(b)-f(a))g'(c)=(g(b)-g(a))f'(c)$. However can we make the stronger claim that if $g(b)\neq g(a)$ there exists a point $c^*$ which satisfies $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{v(c^*)}{w(c^*)}$$
i.e can we cancel the $u$?
If this claim is untrue, can someone give an exception to this claim? Is this question somehow equivalent to L'Hospital?

$f$ and $g$ can be the constant functions 0, in which case we have (say) $u(x)=0$ and $v(x)=w(x)=10e^x$, and dividing by $g(b)-g(a)$ does not make sense.

@Lavender I have made the necessary change to my question.

The generalized MVT can be used to prove L'Hospital's rule. It (or your variant) cannot be equivalent to the latter, which is only a statement about limits. Anyway, better restrict to one question per post.

Yes you are right - was thinking of a different problem so will delete comment

The answer is positive under the assumption that $u,$ $v$ and $w$ are continuous on $[a,b].$
Let $f(a)=f(b).$ Since $f'\ge 0,$ we get $f'=0.$ Thus $u(x)v(x)=0$ for all $a<x<b.$ As $g(a)\neq g(b)$ there is $c\in (a,b)$ such that $u(c)>0.$ Then $v(c)=0$ and
$${f(b)-f(a)\over g(b)-g(a)}=0={v(c)\over w(c)}$$
Let $f(b)>f(a).$  WLOG we may assume that $f(b)-f(a)=g(b)-g(a).$ The conclusion holds if there is $a<c<b$ such that $v(c)=w(c).$ Assume by contradiction that $v(x)\neq w(x),$ $a<x<b.$ Then by continuity we get $v<w$ or $v>w$ on the interval $(a,b).$ Consider the case $v<w.$ Then
$$\int\limits_a^bu(x)w(x)\,dx=g(b)-g(a)=f(b)-f(a)=\int\limits_a^bu(x)v(x)\,dx$$
Thus
$$\int\limits_a^bu(x)[w(x)-v(x)]\,dx =0$$ We get $u(x)[w(x)-v(x)]=0,$ $a<x<b.$ As $w(x)>v(x)$ we obtain $u(x)=0$ for $a<x<b.$ Hence $g'=0,$ i.e. $g(b)-g(a)=0,$ a contradiction.
The case $w>v$ can be dealt with similarly.
